# Mirth Connect Database Reader not returning a result

Tags: mirth

I'm trying to pull a report that gives a volume of message counts accross all channels using the below postgreSQL block by setting up a channel with the source as a Database reader and the destination as a file writer to store the result in an xlm file in a specific directory. After setting up the channel when I enabled it just stays at a polling state with the below error in the server log.
But when I replaced this block with a simple select query it works. It would be really helpful if you could help me understand where I'm going wrong or does Mirth channel does not read a psql block?

```
declare
  tableName text;
  msgCount int;
  channelName text;
  channelID text;
  countDate date;
  PortNum text;
begin
  raise info ' | CHANNEL NAME | CHANNEL ID | DATE | COUNT | PORT NUM';
  execute 'select CURRENT_DATE-1' into countDate;
  <<"Yesterday's Received Message Count">>
  for tableName in (select local_channel_id from d_channels) loop
    execute 'select count(*) from d_mm' || tableName || ' where connector_name = ''Source'' and received_date between (select CURRENT_DATE-31 || '' 00:00:00.00'')::timestamp and (select CURRENT_DATE-1 || '' 23:59:59.99'')::timestamp' into msgCount;
    execute 'select channel.name from channel inner join d_channels on d_channels.channel_id = channel.id where d_channels.local_channel_id = '|| tableName into channelName;
    execute 'select channel.id from channel inner join d_channels on d_channels.channel_id = channel.id where d_channels.local_channel_id = '|| tableName into channelID;
    execute 'select substring (channel.channel, position (''<port>'' IN channel)+6, 4) AS port from channel inner join d_channels on d_channels.channel_id = channel.id where d_channels.local_channel_id = '|| tableName into PortNum;
    raise info ' | %', channelName || ' | ' || channelID || ' | ' || countDate || ' | '|| msgCount || ' | '|| PortNum;
  end loop "Yesterday's Received Message Count";
end;
$channelLoop$;
```

**Error:**

```
[2021-06-28 04:07:16,410]  ERROR  (com.mirth.connect.connectors.jdbc.DatabaseReceiverQuery:207): An error occurred while polling for messages, retrying after 10000 ms...
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:117)
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.jdbc.DatabaseReceiverQuery.poll(DatabaseReceiverQuery.java:190)
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.jdbc.DatabaseReceiver.poll(DatabaseReceiver.java:111)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.PollConnectorJob.execute(PollConnectorJob.java:49)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm honestly not sure what's happening here.

Mirth is going to take whatever you put as your SQL Query in the DB Reader and use it to create a `java.sql.PreparedStatement` using whichever JDBC driver you have selected. Then it executes the PreparedStatement, passing any parameters if necessary based on whether you used replacement tokens or not.

I do not know if the postgres driver will allow this to be compiled to a prepared statement and executed. It seems like maybe it does since it's not complaining until after you try executing the query.

The problem appears to be that the query does not return a ResultSet. Looking at your code, I think you are sending your output to the postgres log instead?

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I still use the same P-SQL block in the back-end to pull the report manually and it returns the ResultSet.

Comment: I think the error pretty clearly says "No results were returned by the query." I don't see any select statements that don't select into a variable either. What are you doing to actually return something?

Comment: As best as I can tell, the messages you are raising need to be retrieved via the getWarnings() method on the statement object, but they are not part of a ResultSet.